# Nodejs cheerio returns undefined when web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I was trying to **scrape** data from a website called NSE, so first I tried to do it in the inspect element console :

(Edited the question)
[image]

```
objs = $('div[class="table-wrap"] > table > tbody > tr > td').slice(0, 8)
objs.map((i,element) => console.log($(element).text()))
```

I get the output :

```
401.20
417.00
- 
411.45
361.10 
441.30 
No Band
-
```

So I was happy as I got the what I wanted.
But then when I went to my vscode and tried to make a script for it, the same code returned Some Random values I guess. Below is the code :

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const axios = require("axios")

const url = "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=SBIN";

async function getDataFromNse() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url)
    let $ = cheerio.load(data)
    const objectArray = $('div[class="table-wrap"] > table > tbody > tr > td').slice(0, 8)
    objectArray.map((i,element) => console.log($(element).text()))
}

getDataFromNse()
```

I get the output:

```
Indicative Equilibrium Price (In )
-
Indicative Equilibrium Quantity
-
Final Price (In )
                                                                    
-
Final Quantity
-
```

I have no idea where are these values in inspector. **And in the console i'm getting the right numerical values**.
If anybody could help, I would really appreciate it!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using `Array.map`, the element comes before the index. Can you try `objectArray.map((element, i) => console.log(element.innerText))`

Comment: @violet yes I changed what you asked but still I'm getting `undefined` :(

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question too that when I tried it on inspect element console, I'm getting the desired values so it means the placement of (i, element) was correct...

Answer (score 0):

innerText is a DOM node property so browsers have those and node doesn't.

To get the text for a cheerio node use:

```
$(element).text()
```

Comment: Hey, I edited the question based on your answer but still the values are incorrect, to check it I tried the same code on console, it worked fine but in the script it prints something else as mentioned in question. Please do take a look if you can!

Comment: It looks like you want data from a [xhr](https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=SBIN&section=trade_info) - that won't be in your cheerio.